# Select com LIKE com argumento %

Tags: c#, sql, select, where

Estou tentando realizar um select, utilizando `LIKE` e definindo o argumento %:

> WHERE title LIKE '%computer%' localiza todos os títulos de livro com a palavra 'computer' em qualquer lugar no título do livro.

fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179859.aspx

Porém, quando executo a string de comando direto no SQL Server Management Studio, executa certinho, e quando tento executar via programa, o mesmo me retorna em branco.

Código `SELECT`:

```
    public DataTable Qgrid_estoque_cod_tipo_1(int tipo, int tipo1, string codigo, int inicio, int fim)
    {
        conexao.bd_string();

        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conexao.sqlconn);

        DataTable grid_produtos = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            conexao._sql = @"SELECT b.descricao AS TIPO, a.familia AS FAMILIA, a.sub_familia AS 'SUB FAMILIA', a.codigo AS CÓDIGO, a.descricao AS DESCRIÇÃO, a.etq_un AS UNIDADE, a.bloq, a.etq_loc AS LOCALIZAÇÃO
                             FROM Estoque AS a
                             LEFT JOIN Tipos_estoque AS b
                             ON a.tipo = b.tipo
                             WHERE a.tipo = @tipo AND a.codigo LIKE '%@codigo%' AND a.id BETWEEN @inicio AND @fim OR a.tipo = @tipo1 AND a.codigo LIKE '%@codigo%' AND a.id BETWEEN @inicio AND @fim";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(conexao._sql, sqlconn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tipo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tipo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tipo1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tipo1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@codigo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = codigo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@inicio", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = inicio;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fim", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fim;

            sqlconn.Open();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(grid_produtos);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            sqlconn.Close();
        }

        return grid_produtos;
    }
```

Comment: Tente usar o método `AddWithValue` desta forma `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", "%" + codigo + "%");` desta forma acredito q funcionara.

Comment: Vc tbm tera q mudar a consulta para `like @codigo` ao invés de `like '%@codigo%'`

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado, por favor, se puder responder a pergunta, para colocar como respondida muito obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o método `AddWithValue` para passar o valor para o parâmetro `@codigo` desta forma:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", "%" + codigo + "%");
```

e mude a instrução correspondente ao `like` da sua consulta SQL para:

```
like @codigo
```

ao invés de:

```
like '%@codigo%'
```